# Google cloud storage to bigquery policy tags don't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

**Context**

On Airflow using the [GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq/index.html#module-contents) to load files from Google cloud storage into BigQuery.
Schema as per [Bigquery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#tablefieldschema) table schema.
Policy tags implemented as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security-intro), tested manually via the UI - works as expected.

**Blocker**
The policy tags are not implemented when the load completes, even though it's specified in the schema fields. The other schema fields work as expected.

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from google.cloud import bigquery
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator



default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
}

with  DAG(
        'gcs_to_bq',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

  DATASET_NAME="temp"
  TABLE_NAME="table"

  gcs_to_bq_load = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
      task_id='gcs_to_bq_load',
      bucket="temp-bucket",
      source_objects=['dummy_data/data.csv'],
      source_format='CSV',
      skip_leading_rows=1,
      write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
      destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME}",
      schema_fields= 
      [{
        "name": "id",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "type": "INT64",
        "fields": []
      },
      {
        "name": "email",
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "type": "STRING",
        "description": "test policy tags", 
        "policyTags": {
          "names": ["projects/project-id/locations/location/taxonomies/taxonomy-id/policyTags/policytag-id"]
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "created_at",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "type": "DATE",
        "fields": []
      }
      ]
    ,
      dag=dag)


  gcs_to_bq_load
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause**
Known issue [Bug in Python BigQuery API with adding policy tags to a table when using WRITE_TRUNCATE](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Developer-Tools/Bug-in-Python-BigQuery-API-with-adding-policy-tags-to-a-table/m-p/181503#M86).

**Solution**
Use the [bigquery api client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#python) instead of Airflow GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_rows=1, autodetect=True,
)

with open(file_path, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)

job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```